# Не заполняется база данных mysql в C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Я сделал бд с несколькими таблицами в mysql workbench'е и теперь пишу интерфейс на си шарпе.

У меня по идее должно по нажатию кнопки добавить, увеличиваться id на 1 и дальше я заполняю графу "способ оплаты". Потом по нажатию кнопки сохранить у меня должна обновляться таблица.
Но почему-то по нажатию кнопки сохранить  ничего не происходит, нельзя нажать ни на что, пока не остановлю отладку в самой студии. Вот код и интерфейс программа, буду благодарен если найдете ошибку...

На картинке функция `private void paySave_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` это функция кнопки сохранить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace oksyBD
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void tabPage1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dataSet1.payment' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.paymentTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet1.payment);
            paymentBindingSource.DataSource = this.dataSet1.payment;
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dataSet1.oksy' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.oksyTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet1.oksy);
            oksyBindingSource.DataSource = this.dataSet1.oksy;
        }

        private void search_textbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void new_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                panel1.Enabled = true;
                name_textbox.Focus();
                this.dataSet1.oksy.AddoksyRow(this.dataSet1.oksy.NewoksyRow());
                oksyBindingSource.MoveLast();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void edit_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Enabled = true;
            name_textbox.Focus();
        }

        private void cancel_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Enabled = false;
            oksyBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
        }

        private void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                oksyBindingSource.EndEdit();
                oksyTableAdapter.Update(this.dataSet1.oksy);
                panel1.Enabled = false;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void paySearch_textbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void payNew_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                panel2.Enabled = true;
                sposob_textbox.Focus();
                this.dataSet1.payment.AddpaymentRow(this.dataSet1.payment.NewpaymentRow());
                paymentBindingSource.MoveLast();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void payEdit_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel2.Enabled = true;
            sposob_textbox.Focus();
        }

        private void payCancel_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel2.Enabled = false;
            paymentBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
        }

        private void paySave_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show("sasa", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                paymentBindingSource.EndEdit();
                paymentTableAdapter.Update(this.dataSet1.payment);
                panel2.Enabled = false;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Приложите _код_ вместо _скриншота_. | Невозможно вам помочь, не видя определения датасета (типизированный, насколько я понимаю?), не видя, как сделана привязка данных, задана ли `UpdateCommand` у датаадаптера (и какой именно sql-код внутри). | И зачем вам пустые методы?

Comment: Пустые методы для будущего поиска по таблице, сейчас приложу код